# How can I add different float names (respecting the page number) to a custom List of "something"?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats

Good evening, everyone. I'm creating a template for a thesis and I've managed to create float environments other than "Figures" and "Tables". And I'm able to generate a "List of X" for each of theses floats, as you can see at the first image. But I now need to somehow put all these floats in just one "List" respecting the apropriated page number like on the second image.  Any ideas?
In advance, thanks.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Here is my disorganized (sorry) preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
lmargin=3cm,
tmargin=3cm,
rmargin=2cm,
bmargin=2cm,
headheight=15.1pt,
heightrounded
]{geometry} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\addto\captionsportuguese{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize SUMÁRIO\hspace*{\fill}}%
}

\addto\captionsportuguese{
    \renewcommand{\refname}{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize REFERÊNCIAS\hspace*{\fill} }}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{5em}
\cftsetindents{para}{0em}{5em}
\cftsetindents{subpara}{0em}{5em}  
\addto\captionsportuguese{
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill}}}

% ~~~~~~~  Redefinição do nome "List of tables":
\addto\captionsportuguese{
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE TABELAS\hspace*{\fill}}}

\newcommand*{\BeginNoToc}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \edef\protect\SavedTocDepth{\protect\the\protect\value{tocdepth}}%
    }%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}%
    }% 
}
\newcommand*{\EndNoToc}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\protect\SavedTocDepth}%
    }%
}
% -----------------------------------------------


\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries FIGURA } 
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\textbf{ -  }}     
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1,8em}  
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-1mm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-1mm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{-1mm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries TABELA }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{\textbf{ -- } }     
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2em}
\setmainfont{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ~~~~~~ NEW FLOAT ~~~~~~ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill},
name=Ilustração,
]{ilustracao}
\captionsetup[ilustracao]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{ilustracao}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum} 
    {\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries{ILUSTRAÇÃO }}%
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ~~~~~~ NEW FLOAT ~~~~~~ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE ALGORITMOS\hspace*{\fill},
name=Algoritmo,
]{algoritmo}
\captionsetup[algoritmo]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{algoritmo}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}
    {\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries{ALGORITMO} }%
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2,1em}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ~~~~~~ NEW FLOAT ~~~~~~ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE EQUAÇÕES\hspace*{\fill},
name=Equação,
]{equacao}
\captionsetup[equacao]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{equacao}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries{EQUAÇÃO }}%
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1,2em}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ~~~~~~ NEW FLOAT ~~~~~~ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE MAPAS\hspace*{\fill},
name=Mapa,
]{mapa}
\captionsetup[mapa]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{mapa}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries{MAPA } }%
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{-0,7em}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ~~~~~~ NEW FLOAT ~~~~~~ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
listname=\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\normalsize LISTA DE QUADROS\hspace*{\fill},
name=Quadro,
]{quadro}
\captionsetup[quadro]{labelfont=bf}
\PrepareListOf{quadro}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\hspace{-1,3em}\bfseries{QUADRO } }%
    \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1em}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0,7em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{0,8em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubparafont}{\normalfont\itshape}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm} 


\linespread{1,44}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
% \hypersetup{
    %   colorlinks,
    %   linkcolor = ,
    %   anchorcolor =,
    %  citecolor = ,
    %   filecolor = ,
    %  urlcolor = ,
    %  pdfauthor=
    % }

% \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[
alf,abnt-full-initials=no,   % Colocar nome completo;
abnt-etal-list=0,            % Listar todos os autores;
abnt-etal-cite=3,            % Mais de 3 nomes não são citados;
abnt-emphasize=bf,           % Ênfase nas revisas com negrito;
abnt-etal-text = it,         % "et al" em itálico. 
]{abntex2cite}
```

Comment: `\addcontentsline` is passed the file extension to be used.  You could modify `\caption` to do two `\addcontentsline`s.  OTOH, I reccomend that people never use templates.

Comment: Sorry, but my superficial knowledge of Latex doesn't allowed me to understando what you recommend.

Comment: \caption calls \addcontentsline{lof) for figures, which writes a commnd (\contentsline IIRC) in the aux file.  which is executed the next time the aux file is read.  I'm a little fuzzy on the next step, because the lof file is not written until \@starttoc is executed.